# Precise, Multiple Copy and Paste of Polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, metadata, copy, paste

I need to layout parking spaces in QGIS. The spaces are diagonal.

**Is there a way in QGIS to copy a given polygon "Y feet up" and "X feet over" say 10 times?**

**Example**:

- Need to take the initial polygon (yellow) and copy through the lot:
- I'd like to specify:

  - Copy this polygon 6' up and 18' left 10 times
  - Add metadata to each copy such as `spot number`, `reserved by`, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use PyQGIS if you know the translation you need to apply between each polygon

You need first to select the feature you want to duplicate to try the script

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
x = 20
y = 30

with edit(layer):
    for i in range(0, 10): # Loop 10 times so create 10 new features
        x1 = (i + 1) * x
        y1 = (i + 1) * y
        feat1cloned = [QgsFeature(i) for i in layer.getSelectedFeatures()][0]
        geom = feat1cloned.geometry()
        geom.translate(x1, y1)
        feat1cloned.setGeometry(geom)
        # I consider you already have a column 'spot_num' defined with 
        # type String in your layer and you only want to fill it
        feat1clone['spot_num'] = str(i)
        layer.addFeature(feat1cloned)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What are the units for `x` and `y`? Also, how are the properties for each feature updated ("parking_spot_number", etc.)?

Comment: `x` and `y` units are your layer projection units

Comment: For the properties, they are duplicated from your selection. Then, you change them. I've edited my answer but I can't guess your logic to fill each column.